# Which Android phone support FEATURE_AUDIO_PRO?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

I developing a low-latency audio app on Android, and found sth about FEATURE_AUDIO_PRO from https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/audio-latency .

But when I run my app on dozens of phones, every one is FEATURE_AUDIO_PRO support is False. Can someone tell me which Android phone is supported it? Thank you.

Comment: I think very less devices do it. I think it could be better for "FEATURE_AUDIO_LOW_LATENCY" but I'm not much sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely only Google's Pixel devices and flagship Samsung ones, as very few vendors seem to care that much.

Samsung has heavily invested in professional audio, to the point of having their own SDK, before Google finally added the AAudio APIs.

https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/professional-audio

Supported by all Galaxy S and Galaxy Note series, as per [Programming Guide](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/professional-audio/guide).

So those are the models you can be sure to have proper support.